# Count the frequency of values across row every 20 columns

Tags: r

I have a large (5k rows) dataset that looks like this

```
ID  Hour intensity00 intensity01 intensity02 ... intensity59
21    1      0           0           1              2
21    2      1           0           0              1
22    0      0           1           1              0
```

How would I add a column that has the counts of the 0's,1's,2's that are in every 20 columns

So it would split intensity00 - intensity 19 then intensity20 - intensity39 then intensity40 - intensity59 and have the number of 0's 1's and 2's for each 20 column group appended at the end.

I have tried:

```
solution <- table(unlist(temp3[1,3:22]))
```

but I cannot figure out how to use that to iterate over each group of 20 columns and every row.

Answer (score 2):

Here we use `tidyr::pivot_longer()` to create groups by the original column names. Using rounded division of the group size we create the groups. Then we simply `dplyr::count()` to get the tabulation. Finally we `tidyr::pivot_wider()` again to put it into the format you were expecting.

I think it's much easier to work with in this format, but if you need it stitched into your original data as you stated in the question, you can `join` and reorder using the last block of code below.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
d <- replicate(60, sample(0:2, 3, T)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(paste0("intensity", formatC(0:59, width = 2, flag = "0"))) %>% 
  mutate(ID = c(21, 21, 22), Hour = c(1, 2, 0), .before = 1)

d %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("intensity"), names_prefix = "intensity", names_to = "intensity") %>% 
  mutate(grp = floor(as.numeric(intensity)/20) + 1) %>% 
  count(ID, Hour, grp, value) %>% 
  mutate(grp = paste0("grp", grp)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(grp, value), names_sep = "_", values_from = "n")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 11
#>      ID  Hour grp1_0 grp1_1 grp1_2 grp2_0 grp2_1 grp2_2 grp3_0 grp3_1 grp3_2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1    21     1      7      8      5      7      8      5      9      5      6
#> 2    21     2      6      9      5      6      4     10      6      6      8
#> 3    22     0      6     10      4      6      5      9      5      8      7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To return summary results embedded with original data:

```r
  left_join(., d) %>%  
  select(ID:Hour, 
         intensity00:intensity19, 
         starts_with("grp1"),
         intensity20:intensity39,
         starts_with("grp2"),
         intensity40:intensity59,
         starts_with("grp3"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion for how to implement a solution with `mutate` and `sum`. I tested the code with the sample data frame created in the answer by @Dan Adams, and I got the same result.

```
library(tidyverse)

d2 <- d %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  #Frequencies for first group
  mutate(cond1_0 = sum(c_across(3:22) == 0),
         cond1_1 = sum(c_across(3:22) == 1),
         cond1_2 = sum(c_across(3:22) == 2),
  #Frequencies for second group
         cond2_0 = sum(c_across(23:42) == 0),
         cond2_1 = sum(c_across(23:42) == 1),
         cond2_2 = sum(c_across(23:42) == 2),
  #Frequencies for third group     
         cond2_0 = sum(c_across(43:62) == 0),
         cond2_1 = sum(c_across(43:62) == 1),
         cond2_2 = sum(c_across(43:62) == 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the data every *n* column using *split.default*, in my example it is every 5 columns. Then loop through 0, 1, 2 get counts per row using *rowSums*:

```
# example data
set.seed(1); d <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0, 1, 2), 20, replace = TRUE), nrow = 2))
d
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# 1  0  0  0  2  1  2  0  1  1   2
# 2  2  1  2  1  2  0  0  1  1   0

do.call(cbind, 
        lapply(split.default(d, rep(1:2, each = 5)), function(i){
          sapply(0:2, function(x) rowSums(i == x))
        }))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    3    1    1    1    2    2
# [2,]    0    2    3    3    2    0
```